# Only show unique values in a query in Access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a **Things** table. Like below.

```
      KCode    T_Name     Description    EID  

        K31     name1            ssdad         1001
        K32     name2            gfd           1002
        K33     name3            gfdsffsdf     1003
        K32     name2            gfd           1002
        K35     name5            fsfds         1005
        K36     name6            dsgfgd        1006
        K35     name5             fsfds        1005
```

I want to retrieve **T_Name** unique data. And i wanted to show all columns

```
        KCode    T_Name       Description        EID 

         K31     name1            ssdad         1001
         K32     name2            gfd           1002
         K33     name3            gfdsffsdf     1003
         K35     name5            fsfds         1005
         K36     name6            dsgfgd        1006
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct kkcode, t_name, description, eid
from table t;
```

EDIT:

Access doesn't have particularly good functionality in this area.  You could do:

```
select max(kkcode), t_name, max(description), max(eid)
from table t
group by t_name;
```

This returns values for each column, but they are not necessarily from the same row.

Comment: I wanted to display **T_Name** unique values along with all columns.But if i use above query no.of Retrieval records differ when i use only **t_name** in a query **select distinct t_name from table t**